# Not reading the function in a JavaScript Module file, by calling onclick in the html document

Tags: javascript, html, module, onclick

Why when we call a function in 'onclick' in the html document, that function is not read in a JavaScript Module file if there is an 'import'?

Is there a solution to use 'onclick' again in this case?

For example, 'onclick' calls the following:

`<input type="button" value="-" class="dark" onclick="mathfa('-')">`

This function:

```
function mathfa(ma) {
    if (ma == "Percent") {
        varable.po = false;
        varable.eva = false;
        varable.per = true;
        if (varable.box.value.indexOf("^") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("+") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("-") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("*") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("/") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("%") == -1) {
            varable.box.value += "%*";
        } else {
            varable.box.value = varable.box2.value + "%*";
        }

    } else if (ma == 'pow') {
        per = false;
        eva = false;
        po = true;
        if (varable.box.value.indexOf("^") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("+") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("-") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("*") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("/") == -1
            && varable.box.value.indexOf("%") == -1) {
            varable.box.value += "^";
        } else {
            varable.box.value = varable.box2.value + "^";
        }
    } else {
        varable.po = false;
        varable.per = false;
        varable.eva = true;
        varable.box.value += ma;
    }
}
```

In a JavaScript Module file:
   `<script type="module"  src="http://localhost:8080/scripts/script.js"></script>`

I even put this function in another file and imported it in the main JavaScript file, but it didn't work.
In addition, I know that if I call that function by 'addeventlistener', it works, but as I mentioned, my problem is using 'onclick'.

Comment: Using "onclick" requires the function to be a property of the global (`window`) object. You can add `window.mathfa = mathfa;` to the module. Using `.addEventListener()` is generally considered better however, as it's more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I put this answer in the answer section so that others can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using "onclick" requires the function to be a property of the global (window) object. You can add `window.mathfa = mathfa`; to the module.

Using `.addEventListener()` is generally considered better however, as it's more flexible.